# Getting Page not found (404) in Django 1.3.1 from bad url pattern

Tags: django, url, http-status-code-404

I am following along with [this Django blog tutorial](http://codingnstuff.com/2010/01/a-complete-blog-engine-using-django-in-60-minutes/3/) and can not get the url pattern given in the tutorial to work properly. The `url.py` code the author gives is

```
(r'^static/(?P
.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': 'c:/static/adornment'}),)
```

and I adapted it to my Linux set up like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': '/home/sez/blog/static/image.png'}
        ),
)
```

and after going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/image.png` I received the following error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/image.png
'image.png' could not be found
```

**How can I make this work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change up your 'document_root' to be a directory, and make sure your STATIC_URL setting is set to /static/

Comment: Right you are c4urself! I had to make my `settings.py` file's `STATIC_URL = '/home/sez/blog/static/'`. Before it was `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason for the behavior you were experiencing is as follows. You probably have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' included in your INSTALLED_APS in the "settings.py" file. In that case, when you run "manage.py runserver" (and you have DEBUG = True in your "settings.py"), static files will be automatically served from your STATIC_URL by the staticfiles app and not by your 'django.views.static.serve' URL pattern. However, in your case staticfiles app is not set up correctly and won't find your 'image.png' file. You might want to read more about conventional serving of static files here: [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

For that matter, STATIC_URL is not supposed to be a filesystem path like you have now: [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_URL).
When you made it that way, you effectively disabled staticfiles app and your code started working as a result :)

So, to solve your problem "correctly", you need to either make sure that STATIC_URL and the URL path in your "urls.py" are different, for example, make one of them "/static/" and another one "/media/" (or something else), or just remove "django.contrib.staticfiles" from your INSTALLED_APPS altogether if you don't use it. (And, of course, the advice about making 'document_root' a directory was entirely correct. You can read more about using 'django.views.static.serve' here: [Serving static files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development).)